# Why am I in DotNet dependency hell and what can I do to get out?

Tags: c#, json, nuget, assemblies, dependency-management

I have a DotNet 4.6.1 application with MVC and WebAPI. The MVC side has GlobalConfiguration.Configuration and the WebAPI has a dependency on Assembly1

Apparently GlobalConfiguration.Configuration in System.Web.Http has a dependency on "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0", and Assembly1 has a dependency on "Newtonsoft.Json", Version=7.0.1.

I placed those quotations precisely because these are precise dependencies:
When I try to run a ping against my WebApi I get:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies"
```

My web.config was added to by NuGet and created by Microsoft so until now I had not touched it and it was built for me. The structure of the web.config is:

```
<!--Personal Comment: See how configuration has no namespace-->
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <!--Personal Comment: See how assemblyBinding DOES have namespace-->
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <!--Left out all of the other dependentAssemblies for brevity-->
            <dependentAssembly>
                <!--Personal Comment: Take note the upper/lowercase of attributes-->
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral">
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0 newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
                </assemblyIdentity>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The odd thing is, if I go to the .csproj in VSCode and change the reference to Include="Newtonsoft.Json" and remove Version=7.0.0.0, etc... then nothing gets fixed. But if I change Version=7.0.0.0 to Version=6.0.0.0 and direct the hintpath to 7.0.1 then my solution works!

This seems like an awful way to live and to program and I don't like it unless I have to deal with it. According to every article I read online, every question, every answer, they all say "use bindingRedirect" and they use it in the way I tried. My assumption is that bindingRedirect is not working for my code, and I need to know why, or could I somehow reference Newtonsoft.Json twice in my references and tell the compiler to use the 7.0.0.0 code if it's not third-party project?

Comment: is upgradeing everything to latest version option?

Comment: Nope. An Option I have in this scenario is just removing the MVC portion entirely. the MVC was created as bootstrap code and is not being used.

However -- The reason I can't just say "that's the answer" is because I have come across this problem numerous times while maintaining a dotnet 2.0 code base and I need to solve this once and for all, so that I know what to do when it happens again.

Comment: Are you using any form of source control?

Comment: All of our applications were until recently in SVN, but my boss has been moving them to a git client and the solutions I've worked on are all on that git client.

Comment: Just to add to my comment before about why I can't say "just update it all" is not the answer, we're moving to a cloud-based platform that has Continuous Integration and Deployment Scripts. One of the applications I've worked on at some point got upgraded to dotnet4.5 which is breaking the Hudson Build and we're unable to get Automated Deploys working through Hudson. One of the errors that shows up is that "We're looking for Newtonsoft.Json 4.5 but only find 6.0, e.g. dependency hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue a while ago. Try this:

- Remove the Json dependency in any projects that use it.
- Close the solution.
- Delete the SUO file. It has the same name of your solution with a .SUO extension.
- Relaunch the solution.
- Clean the solution.
- Add the desired Json dependency to the projects that need it.
- Rebuild the solution.
- Run to verify.

The reason is that Visual Studio appears to "cache" the references in the SUO file.

If it still misbehaves, set the compiler to verbose and rebuild. It should tell you the exact source of the mismatch in the output.

Comment: Thank you, this is fantastic advice. It doesn't work still, however I set the compiler to "Diagnostic" and I found a whole bunch of references to Newtonsoft.Json and I found "Using this version instead of original version "6.0.0.0" in *package* because of bindingRedirect in web.config (and another where AutoUnify is true). So I see that bindingRedirect is working, but this doesn't make sense why it's not working. What should I be looking for in the output? there are 60,000 lines of debug to go through and I don't think I have the budget to scour through them if I can help it

Comment: Look for the log entries around the moment the error is encountered. What you want to do is identify the component that is causing this first, then try to understand why.

Comment: I'm toasted from like an entire week of this over the last few weeks. I might try to do this again on my own, with your advice, but for now I just added the 6.0.0.0 reference and posted an issue on System.Net.Http.Formatting to get their shit together and remove the dependency version number: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack. Thanks, I'll mark yours as the answer since it's at least a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If all the dependencies are managed using NuGet, you can open `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution` and upgrade each project to the latest version of a package (NewtonSoft.JSON in this case). The older package version(s) will be uninstalled once it is not referenced any more.

Comment: Problem still persists. system.Web.Http seems to be dependent upon 6.0.0.0 and that's what seems to be causing the problem. In this project I can remove System.Web.Http, but in many other projects (one just popped up a moment ago) we can't just remove System.Web.Http, and we can't "upgrade all the things"